# Magento 2 Custom No Route Handler

Tags: magento2

I have added a custom no route handler using the following code

```
<?xml version="0.1"?>
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="handlerClassesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="hello" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Smartie\HelloRouter\App\Router\NoRouteHandler</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Which is all good it addes the handler and i proved it by

```
<?php

namespace Smartie\HelloRouter\App\Router;

class NoRouteHandler implements \Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerInterface
{
    public function process(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        die('woop');
    }
}
```

What i have noticed though is that if i return false in the process function i end up with ***Front controller reached 100 router match iterations***. After looking at the NoRouteHandlerList it seems that by adding my new no route handler it actually replaces all of the no route handlers already added (the default one) and i wondered why?

The following similar code for adding a new router has the effect of appending a new router to the list

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Smartie\HelloRouter\Controller\Router</item>
                <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

***Note***: This is magento 2 version 0.74.0-beta16

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problems and i cannot. Maybe you should update Magento to latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this as well. The crux of the issue is covered here in the documentation:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#dep-inj-mod-type-args

> When the configuration files for a given scope are merged, array arguments with the same name are merged into a new array. **If a new configuration is loaded at a later time, either a more specific scope or through code, then any array definitions in the new configuration will completely replace the previously loaded config** instead of being merged.

(emphasis mine)

In my case, I was adding a custom NoRouteHandler through `{module}/etc/frontend/di.xml`, whereas the core handlers are defined in `{module}/etc/di.xml`. Since 'frontend' is a more specific scope, my custom handler replaced the core handlers rather than adding to them.

Move your `di.xml` from whatever config scope you have it in to the `etc` folder, and all will be well.

See also:

- app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/di.xml
- app/code/Magento/Store/etc/di.xml